# Mongoose - can't access object properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ecmascript-6

I am trying to access the properties of a returned MongoDB (mongoose) find.

If I try to console log the whole object, I can see it all. But if I try to log a property, I get `undefined`. The object is there!

```
function getAll () {
    let d = q.defer();

    User.find({}, function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            d.reject(err);
        }

        for(let user of docs) {
            console.log(user); // This works!
            console.log(user.email); // This returns undefined!
        }

        d.resolve();
    });

    return d.promise;
}
```

Any idea?
I also tried to use JSON.parse in case it was stringified (just to make sure) but it wasn't.

**UPDATE**

So seems like I can access the result using `user._doc.email`.
But what causes this? I don't remember having to do this before.

Comment: What exactly is showing up in your console?

Comment: @RyanO'Hara 'undefined'. Logging the whole user object prints the object as it's supposed to be printed, with all properties and values.

Comment: Can you also provide the bare minimum insertion script with 1 data sample?

Comment: 'for (user in docs)'; not 'of'

Comment: @activatedgeek I can, but I am sure this is unrelated. Because the client end (angularjs) receiving the response is able to access the properties. Anyway I will add it.

Comment: Is typeof user `string` or `object`? what's the schema of email?

Comment: @Omarjmh using in will just return the index number of the document within the returned documents...

Comment: @HankChiu console.log(typeof users); returned 'object'. Also each individual user (within the for ... as loop) is returned as type object. Schema is simply "email: String".

Comment: find returns an array, but that will log object with type of

Comment: I've updated the main post with another clue.

Comment: This is typically because `email` is not defined in the schema. Can you edit your question to show the the schema for `User`?

Comment: @JohnnyHK You were right. I created some sort of models loader for my model classes and I messed up with dynamically loading the schema. Can you please post this as an aswer so I can accept it?

Comment: so you knew the answer the whole time? and you left us clues?

Comment: @Omarjmh No. I have better things to do rather than playing quiz here. I just didn't knew that my Schema was broken. I am not typically setting the Schema, but using a dynamic loader. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If a field in your document shows up when you `console.log` the whole document, but not when you directly access that field, it means the field is missing in the model's schema definition.

So add `email` to the schema of `User`.

Comment: As a relative newcomer, I find this answer very inaccessible. So, more explicitly, how does one add a field to a model's schema? specifically, I'm using asn1.js to parse a certificate, and walking through the tree, I'm having this truoble when trying to access the `blockName` field of a `valueBlock` element. it will show when I output the whole tree with JSON.stringify, but not when I access the blockName property of the valueBlock node

Comment: @CodeJockey This is question and answer is specific to schemas in the MongooseJS library (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition). Are you using Mongoose?