# JSON.stringify shows property value, but cannot access property directly

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, stringify

When trying to access a property of a JSON object directly (the object came from a MongoDB document), I'm getting an undefined value. However, JSON.stringify() does produce a value for that property. How can I access the property directly without having to do a JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) call?

Consider the following code:

```
console.log(p.isFinal);
console.log(p.playoffType);
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(p)).playoffType);
```

The output from these lines is:

```
false
undefined
seed
```

Note: In the example, p =

```
{ _id: 5da0eef8d7772b13dc58d2e1,
  week: 14,
  isFinal: false,
  isPlayoff: true,
  playoffType: 'seed',
  playoffTeams: [ 4, 5 ],
  teams: [] }
```

...so I would expect the output to be:

```
false
seed
seed
```

Note also: if I declare p as an object literal, the direct property call works. It only produces the incorrect results when p is the resulting value from the MongoDB call.

I assume this implies something about the way the value is stored in the MongoDB call, as the property with type string is not recognized as a property until coerced through the parse(stringify(p)) call.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How do you make the mongodb request? Can you share it please?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the answer was related to the MongoDB type, specifically that the properties weren't explicitly declared in the schema. More in this SO post:

[Mongoose - can't access object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36381311/mongoose-cant-access-object-properties?rq=1)

Upon adding the "playoffType" property to the schema (snippet below), the direct p.playoffType call works as expected.

```
const ffMatchupSchema = new Schema({
  teams: {type: [
    {
      owner_id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Owner'},
      ff_teams: {type: {}},
      wins: {type: Number},
      isFinal: {type: Boolean}, 
      starter_points: {type: Number}
    }], required: false},
  week: {type: Number},
  winner: {type: {}},
  matchup_id: {type: Number}, 
  isFinal:{type: Boolean},
  isPlayoff: {type: Boolean},
  playoffType: {type: String}, 
  playoffTeams: {type: [mongoose.Mixed]}
})
```